# C recursive function palindrome

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a recursive function with C to check if a word is a palindrome or not (read in both ways).

It's the first time I use this kind of function, but I have a problem, I don't know why it doesn't work, if you could help me, there's my code, thanks :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int palindrome(char c[100],int i, int j)
{
    if (j == i)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Si le premier et le dernier caractère
    // sont les mêmes alors, on peut commencer les tests
    if(c[i] == c[j])
    {
        // On fais les tests pour chaque caractère de la chaine
        return palindrome(c, i++, j--);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char chaine[100] = "radar";
    int pal;

    pal = palindrome(chaine, 0, strlen(chaine)); // Returns : 0 -> False / 1 -> True
    printf("%d", pal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s[strlen(s)]` is 0.  Why is this important?

Comment: I don't understand what u mean

Comment: What I think @Gene means, is that you should not check the string terminator in your comparison.

Comment: Why ? How should I do tho ?

Comment: Think back to when you first started [reading your beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) about arrays and array indexes. You have an array of five characters, with indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. Now what does `strlen(chaine)` returns? It returns `5`! Is that a valid index of a character in your string? No. Now take some time to think about how you can make it a valid index of the last character.

Comment: Hello @Theo, I can see the answer you have accepted is **wrong** and will segfault if given an even length string. Could you please consider accepting the one that is actually right ? Your post is very high in search results it would be very helpful to anyone searching this question !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modified code : 
    1) If first index is 0 , then last index should be strlen(chaine) - 1.
    2) You were passing same values of i and j in the recursive call  , you need to use pre-increment and post-increment operators.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int palindrome(char c[100],int i, int j)
{

    if (j == i)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if(c[i] == c[j]) // Si le premier et le dernier caractère sont les mêmes alors, on peut commencer les tests
    {

        // On fais les tests pour chaque caractère de la chaine
        // increment and decrement first 
        // You were passing same values every time (0 and 4)
        return palindrome(c, ++i, --j);

    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;

}

int main()
{

    char chaine[100] = "radar";
    int pal;
    // Last index should be strlen(chaine) - 1
    pal = palindrome(chaine, 0, strlen(chaine)-1); // Returns : 0 -> False / 1 -> True
    printf("%d", pal);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are really discouraged, especially if it doesn't ***clearly*** say what changes you made.

Comment: I have included comments for what changes I have made

Comment: Thanks dude, So, in C, to increment, decrement it's not i++ or j++ or l-- its ++i, --j etc.. If I understood well ? Thanks for this, it worked

Comment: @Theo Perhaps you should take a few steps back, and start over with a [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: Wrong ! Segfaults with even-length strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems with your recursion. First, `i++` and `j--` pass the values of `i` and `j` with the post increment/decrement applied as a *side effect* after the next call to `palindrome` has already been made. Instead you need:

```
        return palindrome (c, i + 1, j - 1);
```

Next, what happens if `chaine` has an *even number of characters?* `i` never equals `j`. You need to update your test to break recursion to:

```
    if (j <= i)
        return 1;
```

Lastly, you are attempting to read the *nul-terminating* character when you call `palindrome` in `main()` using `strlen(chaine)`, instead you need:

```
    pal = palindrome (chaine, 0, strlen (chaine) - 1);
```

Putting that together, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int palindrome (const char *c, int i, int j)
{
    if (j <= i)
        return 1;

    if (c[i] == c[j])
        return palindrome (c, i + 1, j - 1);

    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *chaine = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "radar";
    int pal;

    pal = palindrome (chaine, 0, strlen (chaine) - 1);

    printf ("chaine : '%s' %s a palindrome\n", chaine, pal ? "is" : "is not");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/recursive_palindrome
chaine : 'radar' is a palindrome

$ ./bin/recursive_palindrome amanaplanacanalpanama
chaine : 'amanaplanacanalpanama' is a palindrome

$ ./bin/recursive_palindrome catfish
chaine : 'catfish' is not a palindrome
```

(for the curious, it is *"a man a plan a canal panama"*)

Comment: You are the only person who noticed `i` and `j` passing each other without ever being equal. Great job ! You get an upvote

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your passing j value as strlen(chaine) instead of strlen(chaine) - 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int palindrome(char c[100],int i, int j) {
    if (j == i)
        return 1;
    else if(c[i] == c[j])
        return palindrome(c, ++i, --j);
    else
        return 0;
}

int main() {
    char chaine[100] = "radar";
    int pal;
    pal = palindrome(chaine, 0, strlen(chaine) -1 ); // Returns : 0 -> False / 1 -> True
    printf("%d", pal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong. Try it with an even length string, it will segfault.

Answer (score 0):

If you can achieve what you are looking for without using recursion do the following. Read the word into a list on and then reverse the word into another list and if they match you have a palindrome.

Comment: Yes, but I want to try to do it in recursive

Answer (score 0):

If you use `strlen(chaine)` you just need to consider the number of comparisons, or calculate them inside `palindrome()`. If you pass the first and last indexes then you need to consider odd and even strings. This is why your program fails...

#### examples

- `12344321` is checked comparing `1-1` `2-2` `3-3` `4-4`
- `abcdXdcba` is checked comparing `a-a` `b-b` `c-c` and `d-d`

So a string of size 8 or 9 requires 4 comparisons for a positive conclusion, the size divided by 2.

So you may not need 2 parameters...

#### an iterative version

In `C` this means

```
int isPal(const char* str)
{
  char*  p    = (char*)str;
  size_t size = 0;
  while (*p++ != 0)++ size;  // strlen
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size / 2; i += 1)
      if (*(str + i) != *(str + size - i - 1))
          return 0;  // exit at 1st different
  return 1;           // all equal
}
```

- the `while` loop gets `size`
- the `for` loop does the comparisons

#### a recursive version

Recursion turns the `for` loop into (recursive) function calls. The size is computed at first, not in every recursion, since it is clear that it just decreases by 2 at each call.

In `C` this means

```
int isPal_r(const char* str, const size_t size)
{
  if (size < 2) return 1;  // trivial
  if (*str != *(str + size - 1)) return 0; // not palindrome
  return isPal_r(str + 1, size - 2);  // try inner string
}
```

#### a test program

This example gets the strings from the command line, since it is a bit frustrating to

- run the program
- then wait for prompt
- then key each string in and press ENTER

And non-interactive programs can be scripted...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int  isPal_r(const char*,const size_t);
void test_isPal(const char*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "\nPlease enter strings on the command line: "
            "Usage: program "
            "str1 str2 ...\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "     %d arguments.\n     Return 1 for a palindrome, or 0\n\n",
        argc - 1);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i += 1)
        test_isPal(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}

void test_isPal(const char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL) return;
    fprintf(stderr, "\nstring is \"%s\"\n", str);
    char*  p    = (char*)str;
    size_t size = 0;
    while (*p++ != 0) ++size;  // strlen
    int res = isPal_r(str, size);
    fprintf(stderr, "     isPal_r() returned %d\n", res);
}

int isPal_r(const char* str, const size_t size)
{
    if (size < 2) return 1;  // trivial
    if (*str != *(str + size - 1))
        return 0;                       // not palindrome
    return isPal_r(str + 1, size - 2);  // try inner string
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions
//46558406/c-recursive-function-palindrome
```

#### some tests

```
SO C> p radar noon abcdedcba 121 A abcdx1cba stack
     7 arguments.
     Return 1 for a palindrome, or 0


string is "radar"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "noon"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "abcdedcba"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "121"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "A"
     isPal_r() returned 1

string is "abcdx1cba"
     isPal_r() returned 0

string is "stack"
     isPal_r() returned 0

SO C> p

Please enter strings on the command line: Usage: program str1 str2 ...

SO C> p "radar noon radar"
     1 arguments.
     Return 1 for a palindrome, or 0


string is "radar noon radar"
     isPal_r() returned 1

SO C>
```